# Preserving whitespace in haml views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In order to display a drop down field with nested items, I have a function which outputs an array of page titles and ids. This array has strings with whitespace like below:

```
[["Parent", 2] , ["  - Child", 3] , ["   -- Grandchild", 4]]
```

Using rails form helper in a haml view, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
= select("page", "page_id",  [["Parent", 2] , ["  - Child", 3] , ["   -- Grandchild", 4]])
```

**How can I do this while preserving the whitespace in my array?**

The output should be a drop down with whitespace in tact so that the list appears nested like this:

```
  Parent
    - Child
     -- Grandchild
```

I have tried [Haml's tilde](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#tilde) for whitespace preservation but this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `&nbsp;` and `html_safe` like this:

```
= select("page", "page_id", [["Parent", 2] , ["&nbsp;- Child".html_safe, 3] , ["&nbsp;&nbsp;-- Grandchild".html_safe, 4]])
```